# DynamicLink url truncated on SMS

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

We are currently testing with a Samsung device.
As shown in the attached photo below, DynamickLink's address is not recognized.
Is there a workaround?[image]

Comment: that's the SMS app problem, not your problem. Probably you can try using some url shortening service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems out of your control, but it looks like the SMS app does not recognise `.link` as a domain and therefor stops at `.li`.

Use another, more common domain and it should work everywhere. Alternatively use another link shortening service like https://goo.gl or something.